# How can I valid random names fields in Yii?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model, yii2-validation

I have a lot of fields generated from loops. I would like to validate them through validation rules (integer). I don't know how to throw so many fields with random names into the model to the rules () function. How can I validate fields without a model?

View:
`<?= Html::input('number', 'file[' . $indexRow . ']' . '[' . $indexCell . ']', $cell, $options = ['class' => 'form-control', 'filter' => 'intval', 'integer']) ?>`

Controller:

` public function actionEdit($fileName)
    {

```
    $siteHelper = new SiteHelper();
    $editForm = new EditForm();

    $preparedRows = $siteHelper->prepareRows($fileName);
    $preparedHTML = '';

    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {

        $post = Yii::$app->request->post();

        if (isset($post['file'])) {

            $dataFile = $post['file'];
            $preparedRows = $siteHelper->updateExcelFile($fileName, $dataFile);

            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Plik został zaktualizowany!');

        } else if (isset($post['EditForm'])) {
            $events = $post['EditForm']['events'];
            $preparedHTML = $siteHelper->prepareHTML($events, $preparedRows, $fileName);

            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Wygenerowano plik PDF!');
        }
    }

    $viewParameters = [
        'rows' => $preparedRows,
        'editForm' => $editForm,
        'scoreHTML' => $preparedHTML,
        'downloadLink' => Url::toRoute(['site/download', 'fileName' => $fileName])
    ];

    return $this->render('edit', $viewParameters);
}`
```

Model:
`
class EditForm extends Model
{
    public $events;

```
public function rules()
{


    return [
        [['events'], 'required'],
        ['events', 'integer'],
    ];
}
```

}`

Comment: why many fields with random name?

Answer (score 0):

When you have an array you can use **each** validator:
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-eachvalidator

The validation function should be:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
         [['events'], 'each', 'rule' => ['required']],
         [['events'], 'each', 'rule' => ['integer']],
    ];
}
```

You may need to avoid multidemnsional array in html and render the field like this:

```
<?= Html::input('number', 'file[' . $indexRow . '-' . $indexCell . ']', $cell, $options = ['class' => 'form-control', 'filter' => 'intval', 'integer']) ?>
```

later you can "explode" the row cell index *(isn't it supposed to be col?)* to identify the row and the column.

```
$rowCellIndecies = explode('-', $rowCellIndex);
```

explode function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php